# cordova plugin to allow one screen landscape only?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I've tried several Cordova plugins to achieve this but none seem to work anymore. Are there any working plugins Android 6.0 that will allow me to set both landscape/portrait (auto) on my index page then landscape only on all other pages within my app?

I've tried about 4 plugins, following documentation to the tee and nothing.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set the preference in your **config.xml**.

Just write this line to set phone orientation to **landscape** only.

```
<preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />
```

For just only one screen your have set the orientation programmatically when screen loads with the help of this [plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation).

For that particular screen you can call this init function onload like this in **HTML**.

```
<body onload="init()">
```

Or you can call the jquery Document.ready().

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   init();
 });
```

Init function is just to add event listener "deviceready" which will fire only on the device. After that you can use the Device API.

```
function init(){
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

function onDeviceReady() {
   // set to landscape
   screen.lockOrientation('landscape');
}
```

Then when you move out from that particular screen you can set jquery unload method like this.

```
 $(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
     // allow user rotate
     screen.unlockOrientation(); 
     // or set the Orientation to portrait
     screen.lockOrientation('portrait');
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  That's the plugin I've been having problems with, I understand the second section of code is for the HTML file within a <script> tag at the bottom, but where to I put the first set of code? I appreciate the comment, been racking my brain on this one.

Comment: Man, I really appreciate the help, but I tried both the jQuery and then next the attaching onload to the body take (removing the jQuery option). I'm almost wondering if the project is corrupted project or the plugin is bugged (thoughts?). Gonna try to create a new project and copy my www folder to it, then readd the need plugins etc. Put prob won't get around to that until tomorrow, busy day. I really appreciate your solution for something I could try out today, even though busy :)

Comment: Any errors ? What happening when your are trying the above code ?

Comment: @joseph update my answer jquery unload method is deprecated and removed from the latest version so that may be the issue. Now try this new code and let me know

Comment: Damn this is frustrating, I tried it out, but what happens it everything builds successfully, the plugin doesn't work in-app (screen orientation never locks). I'm going to make a project from scratch real quick and try that out.

Comment: I'll make an answer so others can see, but after some changes your solution worked like magic!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's what did it. AJs solution worked but I had to ensure a few things first...

- cordova.js is linked to the index.html (or w/e page you're using)
- I also needed to add a link to the plugin js file:
  /plugins/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation/www/screenori‌​entation.js
- Then I needed to add the plugin to the config (this can be done when installing the plugin by using --save

  - Followed AJ's instructions above, which I've marked as the solution.

One last thing, the updated unload option he provided still didn't work, so on the page I want unlocked, I used his solution just added the unlock option example:

```
$(function() {
init();
});

function init(){
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}
function onDeviceReady() {
screen.unlockOrientation();
}
```